# How to get rid of an old anchor-cli version?

Tags: anchor

```
$ avm install latest
Version 0.25.0 is already installed
$ anchor -V
anchor-cli 0.24.2
```

Just switched over to using avm to install anchor-cli instead of npm anchor-cli. But the version is still stuck on the npm version? Any ideas how to force it to switch over to the new version, 0.25.0.

avm is already in the path, I added this to the `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH="/root/.avm/bin:/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
npm uninstall -g @project-serum/anchor-cli
```

Then run `avm use latest` again and restart the terminal. Some combination of these actions will allow avm version of anchor to run.